# RequireJS and 3d party dependencies

Tags: jquery, requirejs, dependencies

I have to use an existing js-library (A) which I cannot modify which in turn uses a 3d party js-library (B).

Both A and B depend on jQuery but only B is AMD compliant:

```
 (function (root, factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            return define('B', ['jquery'], function ($) {
                return factory($, root);
            });
        } else {
            return factory(root.jQuery, root);
        }
    })(window, function ($, window) {

    // Extend $ (jQuery) with a function myFunction
}
```

The script load order is:

1. require.js + requireconfig.js
2. jquery.js
3. B.js
4. A.js

The problem is that when A tries to use $.myFunction it is undefined.

What should my RequireJS-configuration file look like so that $.myFunction is not undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Since module `A` is not AMD compliant and depends on both `jquery` and module `B`, module `A` needs a [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) in your `requireconfig.js`.

It sounds like you do NOT need a shim for module `B` (since it is AMD compliant)<strike>, but you could also add it if you like</strike>.

The paths in the config are relative to the location of the `requireconfig.js` file.

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        "jquery": "your/path/to/jquery",
        "A": "your/path/to/A",
        "B": "your/path/to/B"
    }
    shim: {
        A: ["jquery", "B"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect. You should not ever define a `shim` for modules that call `define`. The results of doing so are undefined.

Comment: Thanks, @Louis.  Fixed.